# Laravel 5.7 check if email is verified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

How I can check if the email is verified in Laravel 5.7?

I think, that may be with:

```
if(!Auth::user()->email_verified_at) {
    return 'Email not verified!';
}
```

Or is there other methods?

Comment: You can also check this with the verification middleware - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of checking the column directly, you can use the method included with the User model:

```
$user->hasVerifiedEmail()
```

If you read the docs, you'll see Laravel also includes a middleware named 'verified' for limiting access to verified users.